# Battery cable/terminal

Tags: battery-cable

I bought a 2017 Ford Focus hatchback SE the end of June 2019. Its now September 2019 and I took my car to have oil change, tires rotated, battery looked at, any way the works.

Since there wasn't any paperwork or notice to tell me when it was changed last, and dealer wont return my calls, I take it to the shop. the mechanic is looking at how dark my oil is he sees that there is visible corrosion on the battery and said they would clean that up for me and put pads and what not on it. The shop manager comes to me and says, well as the tech unhooked the terminal and was taking it off the battery to do what he needed to do, the corrosion as basically ate through and its now needing to be replaced.

Im thinking for one this is a pretty new car why would this happen? #2 will my warranty I got with the car, manufacturer, bumper to bumber, help pay for some of this? No, why? Its maintenance issue warrants dont cover these. But its 2 years old I shouldn't be worried about battery or battery acid corrosion eating way my cables.

I call the dealer who I bought it from thanking maybe they can help me out. No, why? Well if you would have said something the day of or even a week after the sale that something was wrong we could have done something but its been 3 months there isn't anything.

As a consumer you should check under the hood, under the car ect. And I did do a walk around and looked under the hood, I didn't know I should pull on every hose and clamp and wiggle all the parts and make sure they are all in good working condition. I shouldn't have to go to that extent its a 2 year old car. Mind you, I'm not stupid, I know that if there was corrosion at the time I bought the car that there is a way to clean them and let it be.

So, for my question is this really possible for in 3 months corrosion can eat completely through a cable? Or had it taken longer and this probably was already started before I got the car. And is a 2 year old car going to have this kind of a problem already?

Just needing answers to help this "woman" understand why its her fault/problem after only 3 months.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as "the car is only two years old so there should be no corrosion." If the previous owner removed the battery for some reason, then knocked it over and it leaked acid everywhere, and didn't clean up the mess, you would certainly expect some corrosion. Car dealers routinely steam clean the engine compartment while preparing the used cars for sale, so that sort of misuse isn't obvious. After all, you would expect a car dealer to wash the paintwork and valet the interior, so you can't really complain if they do the same thing to the mechanical parts as well.